# how to prevent browser back to display login page after logged in in inertia js

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

How to prevent browser back to display login page after logged in  in inertia js?
if you login to inertia demo CRM with this url :

**Demo Inertia Js** : https://demo.inertiajs.com/login

afetr loginning you can see login page by browser back again.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have successfully logged in and you go back using history back, the only thing you are doing is previewing how the login page looked like. You aren't doing any request, just visiting your browser's history.

If you go back and refresh the page, you can see that you are now being redirected to the dashboard, which means that you did a request and the server detected you are logged in. As you are logged in, redirects you from `/login` (guest) to `/dashboard` (auth).

So in my opinion there is nothing to solve, you don't need to prevent browser back to display login page, you need a middleware to redirect you out from guest routes if you are logged in, that is it.

Docs:

- [History.back() - MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back)
- [RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware - PingCRM](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php)

Comment: Yes it preview the previous page but it is not a good thing that after login you are seeing login screen, github.com have this feature try it, login and then go back it will prevent you

Answer (score 1):

Reason login page is rendered even logged in is because login page rendering request is not sent to the server.
In the login form submission, you can put additional option to replace the page.
Browser back button will also replace the page and eventually, rendering request gets sent.

```
Inertia.post('/login', {
   email: email, 
   password: password 
}, {
   replace: true 
})
```

Comment: it works it is skipping that page and go to before to the previous one but do not want to that page also, for example I add this to login page now when login and go to dashboard and then go back from history it skip the login page and go to the page before to login but i want not to show that page also

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but here is how I did it,

In the `app.js` file I had to listen to the `success` event to the router. I had to leverage that because after you logout, and you navigate via browser history keys (back and forward), there are no requests sent to the backend. However, checking if the route was success still works even with just browser history navigation. So we tap into the success event on router like:

```
import {router} from '@inertiajs/vue3';

router.on('success', (event) => {
  let isAuthenticated = event.detail.page.props.auth.user !== null;
  window.localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', `${isAuthenticated}`);
});
```

That's it! Almost. Now, when you navigate back and forth with the history keys, the browser uses 'popstate' to fetch the views from history. We have to listen to that event from the browser when it happens.. Like so:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') === 'false') {
    router.replace('/login');
  }
});
```

Notice the `false` check is a string? It's because `localstorage` stores values as strings only.

That's it, we are done! If you are still not satisfied by that split of a second when the page kind of shows up before going to the login page, you can stop the propagation like:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```